# java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "api.openweathermap.org": No address associated with hostname

Tags: android

Please help debug the following code
I have made sure that

1.My Device has Internet access.

2.My Android Manifest file has internet permission.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private StringBuilder stringBuilder = null;
    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private String url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appid=48b076c80a0b064d62117d19015db014";
    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.temp);

        JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = response.getJSONObject("main");
                            float tempr = (float) jsonObject.getDouble("temp");
                            stringBuilder.append(tempr);

                            textView.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.v("Not working", error.getMessage().toString());

            }
        });
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
    }
}
```

The logcat shows the following report:

> java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host
>   "api.openweathermap.org": No address associated with hostname

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="androidhive.com.volley5">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
       <activity
           android:name=".MainActivity"
           android:label="@string/app_name"
           android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
     </application>

   </manifest>
```

Comment: What device are you testing on? Have you retried again?

Comment: I tried on  Genymotion emulator 
Samsung Galaxy S5 4.4.4-API 19-1080X1920

Comment: How does your manifest look like?

Comment: @Felix Edelmann i have edited my question and added the manifest file..

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue when I was working with *openweathermap* API.

There are a few steps that solved my issue.

*First* of all, turn on *emulators* **wifi** and **mobile data** both.

*Second*, reset permission in **androidmenifest.xml** file. Add internet permission and also add read and write external storage.

Then run the app. Hope it will solve your error as it solved mine.

Answer (score -1):

**Hello.**
Today I faced this problem.
There was simply no internet on the phone.
I was helped by checking the connection to Wi-Fi